# How to INSERT now() + INTERVAL in Postgres 9.x

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to `INSERT` a future date into a `timestamp with time zone` column in a table in Postgres 9.6.2. I'd like this date to be the current transaction time plus an arbitrary interval, such as 1 hour.
I understand how to do date/time arithmetic in a `SELECT` statement, but the same syntax of `NOW() + INTERVAL '1 hour'` does not seem to be valid in an `INSERT` statement.

Aside from accomplishing this at the application level, is it possible to accomplish this using a single `INSERT` statement using date/time arithmetic? If not, what would best practice be in this situation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you have it right - this worked for me:

```
insert into barcode (id,barcode,active,created,updated) 
    values (111,'23432', true, NOW() + INTERVAL '1 hour',NOW());
```

I am running Postgres 9.4.13.

Comment: This is quite interesting. The SQL you've provided works exactly how I want, and exactly how I expected this to work normally, but only when I run a full query with this syntax. When running the query with my node.js middleware AND in pgadmin, I get syntax errors.

`error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "NOW() + INTERVAL '1 hour'"`

Is there something I'm missing here about the correct syntax to use with quotes? I'm getting the impression that pgadmin appends quotes around values when you're editing table data.

Comment: It is likely an escaping issue with the quotes

Comment: You're right. It was an escaping issue with the quotes. It looks like postgres fails to parse the expression `NOW() + INTERVAL '1 hour'` if it's wrapped in double quotes. That's pretty confusing. Marked you as the correct answer since you answered my initial query correctly! Thank you!

Comment: In Postgres double quotes are used for **delimited identifiers**.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: Totally correct. It appears like the middleware I was using (node-postgres) was appending the double quotes when creating a prepared statement. So was pgadmin, when I was testing syntax by editing data manually.

Comment: @ajxs I met the same problem, do you know how to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67088069/escape-string-when-prepare-php-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment118584126_67088069

Comment: @quynt It was an issue with the query string being enclosed in double quotes by the database driver. The issue was specific to the database driver I was using, in this case `node-postgres`. I can't recall the exact solution I arrived at to make this work with that middleware.