# Escape string when prepare php postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I am preparing data before execute postgresql in php. The query is

```
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(pin_code, started_at, ended_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
```

I can prepare the params like this

```
$test_data = array(
    '1010', 
    "NOW()", 
    "NOW()",
);
```

but not

```
$test_data = array(
    '1010', 
    "NOW()", 
    "NOW() + INTERVAL '1 DAY'",
);
```

I guess the problem is related to the single quotes `'`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Let PHP create the timestamp-values, not the database. This is because you can't prepare a database function or calculation like you try in your current code.

Comment: And something else, you might want to take a look at the date range datatype: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

Comment: If you want `now()`, you would include this in the SQL directly - `VALUES (NOW())` for example.

Comment: I am trying to use `executeMultiple` with different time related to NOW, so I wonder if there is some way to prepare the params like that

Comment: @quynt: No, not possible and no need for: PHP can handle this for you

Comment: Maybe it is a bad practice, but this type of method is used  by *Japanese engineers* and I have to follow the legacy code