# how to insert the current date in like postgresql

Tags: sql

how can I insert the current day into the like operator analogous to the f string in python?

[image]

I need to filter the field that contains the dates to calculate the amount of orders at the moment.

Comment: Column registrator data type?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249299/how-to-insert-now-interval-in-postgres-9-x

Comment: Don't use images for code, use properly formatted text instead. I want to copy-and-paste column names. And that tiny image text is pretty hard to read on my small laptop screen.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: I think you should check you table data becuase this query look fine to me and should filter the rows as per where registrator like '%data%'